# translate cosine curve to sine curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

```
Find two different phase shifts that translate the cosine curve onto the sine curve.
Write an equation for both new cosine curves using each phase shift.
```

Image is given in hyperlink.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CKLg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Sin($\theta - \pi/2$)= Cos($\theta$)

Sin($\theta + 3\pi/2$)=Cos($\theta$)